# Quantumnik plugin replacement?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mapnik

I am looking for export QGIS Style in MapNik (so, his .xml format)
I see that Quantumnik plugin can do that, but is not supported anymore (and cannot be installed at all) .

[image: Can't install Quantumnik]

Is there any alternative than installing QGIS 1.99 ?